# ordered sets in redis: random output in case of score ties

Tags: redis, sortedset

I have an ordered set in Redis (I am actually using a python client https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py), for example:

```
zadd myset 1 key1
zadd myset 1 key2
zadd myset 1 key3
zadd myset 0 key4
```

Note that 3 keys have the same score.

Using ZRANGE, i would like to get the top 2 entries (i.e lowest scores). "key4" will always be the first result as it has a lower value, but I would like the second return value to be randomly selected between the ties: key1,key2,key3.   ZRANGE actually returns the keys in the order they are indexed: "keys1" is always my second result:

```
zrange myset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "key4"
2) "0"
3) "key1"
4) "1"
5) "key2"
6) "1"
7) "key3"
8) "1"
```

any idea?
thanks,
J.

As kindly requested by [Linus G Thiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295262/linus-g-thiel), here are more details about my usecase:

I would like to use zsets to  perform a simple ranking system. I have a list of items, for each one a score representing the relevance of the item. For the cold start of my system, most of the scores will be identical (i.e 0), and I would like to randomly select among the items having the same score. Otherwise I will always return the exact same lexicographic ordering, which will introduce a bias in the system.

The solution you propose, using one specific set for each duplicated score value will work. I will give it a try.

Thanks,

Comment: Fyi, although this doesn't answer the question: `Lexicographical order is used for elements with equal score` http://redis.io/commands/zrange

Comment: @Mahn is right, you can't do this with a sorted set alone. Perhaps you could keep a separate set for each score, and use `SRANDMEMBER` on that. I can't think of a better solution for this -- perhaps if you tell us a little bit more about your use case.

Comment: @Mahn, yes you right, the indexing order is not taken into account

Comment: @LinusGThiel, thanks, I just detailed my usecase in the question, thanks!